# Peugeot fob buttons central locking not working

Tags: key, peugeot, central-locking

Remote fob central locking is not working in Peugeot 307 from 2007. Key itself opens and starts the car, but central locking buttons don't open or close the car. Central locking button inside the car works. I have been to TIMPSONS and they sold me brand new remote, as old one had a electric fault, but new one is not working either. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Typically new remotes require being linked to the car. So, take the remote back to who sold it to you and either have them make it work, or get your money back.

Comment: I can't take it back- it was bought from private person who will not take it back... Any other ideas?

Comment: This is an international site, so I don't know who TIMPSONS is. Thought it was a retail outlet that sold you the new remote.

Comment: No, my apologies- Timpson is a key cutting place. Remote is working as it been tested, its just not linked to my car....

Comment: The place that sold it to you should have linked it to the car for you. I will offer some suggestions in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The new remote needs to be programmed to the car. It should be in the owners manual, but I couldn't find one online. What I did find online, you can try the following;

1. Insert key into ignition and turn to RUN, not start
2. Wait 10 seconds
3. Press the lock button for 10 seconds
4. Turn the key to OFF.
5. Remove the key and wait for 10 seconds
6. Press the lock button, the dash lights should come on

*Note: You will need to do this for each key you have that is not working.*

If it doesn't work, try it a second time. If still no success, check out the steps on this [web page](http://www.programyourkeys.com/Peugeot_206_Key_Remote_Control_Reprogramming_Instructions.html). It is for a 206, but it might work.

Comment: Here is another site with some instructions how to deal with central locking on a Peugeot. https://www.askthemechanic.co.uk/remote-key-programing/peugeot

Comment: I have tried the first option numerous times and is not working... I will try the others this evening...

Comment: Not trying to be too pedantic, but in the answer given, you cannot perform step 4 without having first turned the key to the OFF position. I’m not blaming CharlieRB as it is clear that he has copied what he saw online. However, the person who wrote the original steps was careful enough to say that the key needs to be turned to a certain position at the beginning. I think that they should be equally careful to put in the step that the key needs to be turned to the OFF position. Just trying to help and not trying to be a jerk.

Comment: CharlieRB's answer seemed to clear to me, as the key can't be removed without first being turned back to OFF. Nevertheless, I've edited his answer to add an explicit step.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the key into the ignition
Do not turn on the engine
Open the diver door
Wait for 10 seconds
Remove the key
Wait for 10 seconds
Press the lock bottom.